# Excel VBA Macro ignores Column width command

Tags: excel

All
When I write the following excel VBA code, macro applies the columns width 10.86 to the entire sheet, and ignore the terms related to columns (A, B, C)., Could any one help?, thanks in advance

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 17.86

Columns("B:C").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 19.86

Columns("D:I").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 10.86
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is on the sheet? Note that you don't need to `Select`: `Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.86`, and so on.

Comment: As Ben stated it might be a selection issue and direct references might solve it. Also see if you don't have any Worksheet_Change events running at the same time which might mess with your selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get rid of the Select statements it works properly.  The below link is a good discussion about avoiding Select statements in VBA.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

```
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.86

Columns("B:C").ColumnWidth = 19.86

Columns("D:I").ColumnWidth = 10.86
```

Answer (score 0):

unless there is some other code that changes the selection, this should not happen
try this code, it sets the width in the active sheet

```
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 17.86
    .Columns("B:C").ColumnWidth = 19.86
    .Columns("D:I").ColumnWidth = 10.86
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Another reason `.ColumnWidth =`  can be ignored is if it is set inside a user-defined function because [UDFs are not allowed to set properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1). You have to find a way to set it inside a sub, not a function. If set inside a function, it does not cause an error, it's just ignored.